# Java string.length not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader

I have a file with some data in the format:

```
12345foo \n
24561bar \n
12783apples \n ect.
```

In order to process this data, I am reading it into a program using bufferedreader and placing it into a 2D array with the following code:

```
line = bRead.readLine();
2DArray[x][y] = line.substring(0,5);
2DArray[x][z] = line.substring(5,line.length());
```

I am unsure as to why line.length is apparently giving me `(line.length() - 5)` in this instance.

Comment: Er, it's not. `line.length()` gives you `line.length()`. Are you confused as to the meaning of the second parameter of `substring`? [It's the *offset from the start*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), not the number of characters after `5`. Not that you need to pass a second parameter anyway, if you just want the rest of the string.

Comment: Seems like you might find use in regex `\d` and `\D` for only getting numbers and non-numbers

Comment: What's your expectation? Why do you think line.length() gives you the string's length minus 5?

Comment: Your code will separate `12345` and `foo`, there's nothing wrong about the code, your perception is wrong I think.

Comment: Are you trying to do this? 2DArray[x][z] = line.substring(5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, line.substring() uses the first paramiter to determine offset from the start, and the second paramiter to determine... offset from the start. For example,

`String foo = "barAndSomeOtherStuff";
 System.out.print(foo.substring (5, 12));`

Would output "dSomeOt", as opposed to "dSomeOtherSt."

A good idea for questions like this is to check the documentation before you come to places like StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

line.substring(5);

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader bR = null;

    try {
        bR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("teste.txt"));

        Map<String, String> txt = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String line;

        while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null) {
            txt.put(line.substring(0, 5), line.substring(5));
        }

        txt.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " - " + v));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bR != null) {
            try {
                bR.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:

24561 - bar
12345 - foo
12783 - apples
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to approve and review your code, my first question would be "Why are you using arrays?" Splitting data that logically belong together into a 2D array or a Map, is what I would consider bad code. You clearly have a line item, with an id and a name, so you should have a domain model for such an object.
Here is what I would do.

```
package com.example

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String data = "12345foo\n" +
                      "24561bar\n" +
                      "12783apples\n";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data));
        String line = null;
        List<LineItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 5));
            String name = line.substring(5);
            items.add(new LineItem(id, name));
        }

        items.forEach(lineItem -> System.out.println(lineItem));

    }

    public static class LineItem {
        private final int id;
        private final String name;

        public LineItem(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "LineItem{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code is missing a try block, but it seems I can't edit the code snippet :(